# How to send the enter key press manually in Ansible

Tags: ansible

The Error I am getting from Ansible is"

```
fatal: [192.168.1.10]: FAILED => {"msg": "Incorrect sudo password"}
```

The error is a result of having to press the enter key twice due to a bug. If I SSH into the server and run `sudo su` it hangs until I press enter again then shows the root shell. I am trying to generate a play to resolve the issue. The issue can be fixed by running the command manually on the box and pressing enter a second time after a few seconds:

```
sudo pam-auth-update --remove krb5 tacplus
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I have tried this as a play

```
- name: Fix Double Enter issue
  raw: sudo pam-auth-update --remove krb5 tacplus
  raw: 'enter'
```

I have also tried just asking it to put a random command to trigger the second key press, but since it is not getting a response after entering sudo it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `become_method : sudo` and `become : yes`. Possibly with the `shell` instead of `raw`? Assuming your user can run any command as an escalated privilege.

```
- name: Fix Double Enter issue
  shell: pam-auth-update --remove krb5 tacplus
  become_method: sudo
  become: yes
```

Comment: Still the same problem. Essentially, if I SSH into the box and issue `sudo su`, it will sit on a blank line until enter is pressed a second time. after running `sudo pam-auth-update --remove krb5 tacplus` waiting a few seconds and pressing enter again the issue gets cleared, but the key is that second enter press.